# What are the lowest and highest months in terms of sold tickets in 2017?

Tags: sql

I have a table called tickets which I am using to find the maximum and minimum months in terms of sold tickets in 2017. I have tried using different queries but I haven't been able to find a solution.

First I tried:

```
SELECT
    MIN(mycount) AS Lowest_Month,
    MAX(mycount) AS Highest_Month
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            month(purchase_date) Months,
            count(purchase_date) AS mycount
        FROM
            tickets
        WHERE
            YEAR(purchase_date) = 2017
        GROUP BY
            month(purchase_date)
    ) a
```

this gives me the total number of sales per month in 2017. However, I need to find the month fro the maximum and minimum values. Then I tried:

```
SELECT
    MONTH(purchase_date),
    COUNT(purchase_date) AS counts
FROM
    tickets
WHERE
    YEAR(purchase_date) = 2017
GROUP BY
    MONTH(purchase_date)
HAVING
    COUNT(purchase_date) = (
        SELECT
            MAX(counts) AS Highest_Month,
            MIN(counts)
        from
            (
                select
                    month(purchase_date),
                    COUNT(purchase_date) AS counts
                FROM
                    tickets
                GROUP BY
                    MONTH(purchase_date)
            ) as a
    )
```

This is not working either. Any recommendations?

Comment: please tag with the database platform, show the table definition, and sample data

Answer (score 0):

One method is:

```
with m as (
      SELECT month(purchase_date) Months, count(*) AS mycount
      FROM tickets
      WHERE YEAR(purchase_date) = 2017
      GROUP BY month(purchase_date)
     )
select m.*
from m
where m.mycount in (select min(mycount)
                    from m
                    union all
                    select max(mycount)
                    from m
                   );
```

However, I would be just as inclined to use `UNION ALL`:

```
WITH m AS (
      SELECT month(purchase_date) Months, count(*) AS mycount
      FROM tickets
      WHERE YEAR(purchase_date) = 2017
      GROUP BY month(purchase_date)
     )
SELECT m.*
FROM m
ORDER BY mycount ASC
FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY
UNION ALL
SELECT m.*
FROM m
ORDER BY mycount DESC
FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY;
```

Not all databases support the standard `FETCH FIRST` clause.  You might need `LIMIT` or `SELECT TOP 1` and perhaps other tweaks to the syntax.